# What is this weird code I get from Apiary?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get data, preferably javascript, back from an API.
The code that gets returned is new to me, how do I use it?

This is my js file:

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

request.open('POST', 'https://private-69579b-adtraction.apiary-mock.com/v1/affiliate/products');

request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
request.setRequestHeader('Accept', 'application/json');
request.setRequestHeader('X-Token', '');

request.onreadystatechange = function () {
  if (this.readyState === 4) {
    console.log('Status:', this.status);
    console.log('Headers:', this.getAllResponseHeaders());
    console.log('Body:', this.responseText);
    console.log(apiProduct);
    console.log(apiProduct[0]);
    console.log(apiProduct[0].imageUrl)
  }
};

let apiProduct = {
  'page': 1,
  'pageSize': 20,
  'channelId': 1234567890,
  'programId': 1047411868,
  'currency': 'SEK',
  'minPrice': 200,
  'orderProductsBy': 'priceDesc',
  'inStock': true,
  'market': 'DK',
  'productKeyword': 'byggmax',
  'setEpi': true
};

request.send(JSON.stringify(apiProduct));
```

And this is what gets returned in the console:

```
Status: 200
apiary.js:12 Headers: content-type: application/json
content-length: 554

apiary.js:13 Body: [
  {
    "programId": 1234567890,
    "sku": "abc123",
    "productName": "Playstation 4",
    "productPrice": 129.5,
    "productUrl": "http://www.example.com/store/product_acb",
    "imageUrl": "http://www.example.com/store/product_acb.png",
    "productDescription": "PlayStation 4 redefines rich and immersive gameplay with powerful graphics and speed.",
    "ean": "0711719437215",
    "currency": "SEK",
    "manufacturerArticleNumber": "12345678",
    "manufacturer": "Apple",
    "productCategory": "Consoles",
    "oldPrice": 110,
    "shipping": 100,
    "inStock": false,
    "market": "DK",
    "approvalStatus": 1,
    "extraInfo": {
      "array": false,
      "null": false,
      "number": false,
      "int": false,
      "valueNode": false,
      "object": false,
      "containerNode": false,
      "missingNode": false,
      "pojo": false,
      "integralNumber": false,
      "floatingPointNumber": false,
      "short": false,
      "long": false,
      "double": false,
      "bigDecimal": false,
      "bigInteger": false,
      "textual": false,
      "boolean": false,
      "binary": false,
      "float": false,
      "nodeType": "ARRAY"
    },
    "trackingUrl": "https://track.adtraction.ver/t/t?a=1036556668&as=141&t=2&tk=1"
  }
]
apiary.js:14 {page: 1, pageSize: 20, channelId: 1234567890, programId: 1047411868, currency: "SEK", …}channelId: 1234567890currency: "SEK"inStock: truemarket: "DK"minPrice: 200orderProductsBy: "priceDesc"page: 1pageSize: 20productKeyword: "byggmax"programId: 1047411868setEpi: true__proto__: Object
apiary.js:15 undefined
apiary.js:16 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'imageUrl' of undefined
    at XMLHttpRequest.request.onreadystatechange (apiary.js:16)
request.onreadystatechange @ apiary.js:16
XMLHttpRequest.send (async)
(anonymous) @ apiary.js:34
```

From your responses so far I have deduced that it is indeed JSON. I had actually tried doing this:

```
console.log(apiProduct[0].imageUrl)
```

before, but I got the same result then as now:

```
apiary.js:16 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'imageUrl' of undefined
    at XMLHttpRequest.request.onreadystatechange (apiary.js:16)
request.onreadystatechange @ apiary.js:16
XMLHttpRequest.send (async)
(anonymous) @ apiary.js:34
```

Comment: This looks to be JSON (JavaScript object notation) with some missing syntax, probably for readability. JSON is directly usable by JavaScript -- and most languages

Comment: https://www.copterlabs.com/json-what-it-is-how-it-works-how-to-use-it/

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] to illustrate how you get this data. Also be sure that the data you show here is exactly the same as the data you get in your response in your code. It appears that you are missing some `{}` around the data you show here.

Answer (score 0):

```
var Body = [
{
   "programId": 1234567890,
   "sku": "abc123",
   "productName": "Playstation 4",
   "productPrice": 129.5,
   "etc...": "etc"
   }
]
console.log(Body);
console.log(Body[0]);
console.log(Body[0].productName)
```

This is how you deal with objects in javascript